# How to query from multiple tables Laravel DB

Tags: laravel-5

Im new to laravel db query. I have problem when want to query.

I have two table customer and history. In history it have few column which are customer_id, activity (purchase,buyback), product_type(gold,silver) and quantity. Currently I want to retrieve balance for each of customer. To get balance, purchase - buyback.

```
 -> customer_id | gold_balance | silver_balance
```

Here I attach two part of table and code to be review.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have [models and relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) set up for `customer` and `history`? If yes, you would just have to do something like `Customer::with('history')->get();`, I think?  Also, please don't post images of code - edit your question, add the **relevant** code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a hasMany relationship between Customer and History (maybe called `histories`) and create a custom attribute that loops through histories and add/subtract amount.

Something like this (not tested):

```
class Customer {

  public function histories() {
    return $this->hasMany(History::class);
  }

  public function getBalanceAttribute() {
    return $this->histories->reduce(function($total, $current) {
      $grossAmount = $current->amount * $current->quantity;
      return $current->activity === 'purchase' ? $total - grossAmount : $total + grossAmount;
    }, 0;

  }

}
```